# How to create a phpUnit mock that returns another mock?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I have this Authentication class:

```
<?php

class AuthenticationRepository implements AuthenticationRepositoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(JWTConfig $jwtConfig)
    {
        $this->config = $jwtConfig;
    }

    private function _isVerifiedToken(Token $token, string $publicKey): bool
    {
        $signer = new RS256();
        $publicKey = new Key($publicKey);

        return $token->verify($signer, $publicKey);
    }

    private function _isValidToken(Token $token): bool
    {
        $data = new ValidationData(); 

        return $token->validate($data);
    }

    private function _parsedToken(string $tokenString): Token
    {
        return (new Parser)->parse($tokenString);
    }

    public function decode(string $token, string $publicKey): bool
    {
        $parsedToken = $this->_parsedToken($token);

        return $this->_isVerifiedToken($parsedToken, $publicKey) && $this->_isValidToken($parsedToken);
    }
}
```

And I want to create unit tests using `phpUnit`. So far I have been trying to mock `Lcobucci\JWT\Parser` and would like it returns a `use Lcobucci\JWT\Token` mock like this:

```
        $this->parserStub = $this->getMockBuilder(Parser::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->onlyMethods(['parse'])
            ->getMock();
        $this->tokenStub = $this->createMock(Token::class);
        $this->parserStub
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('parse')
            ->with($this->equalTo($token))
            ->willReturn($this->tokenStub);
```

But it doesn't appear to work as expected. I am also getting an error:
`Deprecated: Return type of Lcobucci\JWT\Claim\Basic::jsonSerialize() should either be compatible with JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used`

Moreover, looking at the documentation I am not able to see any example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks fine. This is not a testing or mocking issue. The way you've configured the mock should work. The problem is a compatibility issue in the code your testing i.e. `Lcobucci\JWT\Claim\Basic::jsonSerialize()` is not compatible. Try updating the `Lcobucci\JW` dependency to a newer version. If you look a the changelog of the https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/releases and compare the version to yours, you might see a note about the fix.

Comment: I have ended up not mocking the library but thanks anyway for the advice.